# Convert array to Image (EBImage) in R

Tags: arrays, r, image-processing, matrix

The package `EBImage` has a `display` function that allows to display `Image`objects, but when `imagematrix`,`matrix` or `array` is an input, it is also possible to display (as a raster).

Now when I try to `combine` multiple images, it is only possible to combine `Image` objects, so since my initial images are in `imagematrix` or `matrix` format, I can't use this `combine` function, then to display multiple images.

So my question is: how to convert a matrix to an `Image` object (EBImage)?
(If you have another function to display multiple matrices as raster image, it helps, too.)

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** use the `Image()` constructor to convert matrices or arrays to `Image` objects.

You can easily switch between plain matrices/arrays and `Image` objects with the help of `imageData()` accessor and `Image()` constructor. Another way to cast a pixel intensity matrix to an `Image` is to use `as.Image()`. See the following example for an illustration of this approach on a single-channel grayscale image.

```
library(EBImage)

## sample grayscale image
f <- system.file("images", "sample.png", package="EBImage")
x <- readImage(f)

## extract pixel intensity matrix from the Image object
m <- imageData(x)

## convert matrix to Image
img <- Image(m)

## combine and display the result
img2 <- combine(img, img)

display(img2, method="raster", all=TRUE)
```

[image]

If your pixel intensities array contains separate color channels for the red, green and blue components, you would additionally specify the `colormode=Color` argument to `Image()`.

```
## get sample pixel intensity RGB array
x <- readImage(system.file("images", "sample-color.png", package="EBImage"))
a <- imageData(x)

## convert back to Image
img <- Image(a, colormode=Color)

## combine and display the result
img2 <- combine(img, img)

display(img2, method="raster", all=TRUE)
```

[image]

In case you have color channels as separate matrices, you can combine them into a color `Image` with the help of `rgbImage()`.

```
## matrices corresponding to red, green and blue color channels
r <- a[,,1]
g <- a[,,2]
b <- a[,,3]

## construct an color Image object 
img <- rgbImage(r, g, b)
```

Comment: Doesn't work here. I get the following error after the final display call. `Error in validImage(x) : object must be an array`. Windows, R Ver 3.4.3

Comment: Which version of EBImage are you using? (You can display the package version by running `packageVersion("EBImage")`). All the above code runs just fine under EBImage release, so in case you have an older version you might want  to upgrade by running `source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R"); biocLite("EBImage")`.

Comment: PackageVersion("EMIage") = ‘4.20.1’. And that is the same AFTER I run your upgrade code. And now on a Mac.

Comment: `library(BiocInstaller)` =
Bioconductor version 3.6 (BiocInstaller 1.28.0), ?biocLite for help

Comment: I figured it out! `biocValid()` said I have 4 packages too new. And then it provided a helpful suggestion: downgrade with biocLite(c("ggplot2", "rlang", "scales", "withr")). Once I did that, it worked! Thanks!